# How to import one .ipynb file from another .ipynb file on google colab?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two file on google colab, first one file1.ipynb another one file2.ipynb. I want to import file1.ipynb from file2.ipynb.

%run MyOtherNotebook.ipynb